# CentOS / Redhat: Give file permission for apache and vsftp

Tags: centos, permissions, redhat, ftp, vsftpd

I use CentOS 5.5 and Apache Webserver on my dedicated Server. My Folder "/var/www/myWebApp" is owned by apache, so that apache can read, write logs, etc..

But now I would like to use very secure FTP (vsftp) to upload my new files. I used to give every user rwx -Acess to "/var/www/myWebApp", but I guess this is way to insecure.

On CentOS I created another user "ftpuser" for uploading files and that has "/var/www/myWebApp" as its home directory. How can I give him the permission to write into  the "/var/www/myWebApp" without giving every user the same rights?

Comment: Please be aware that although the *name* is "very secure", `vsftp` is only more secure relative to other ftp daemons. It still is not a secure protocol. I highly recommend using `sftp` instead, which has the advantage of it probably is already working because the server side is part of `sshd`.

Comment: +1. FTP is inherently insecure, regardless of the name :)

Answer (score 5):

CentOS 5.5 should have filesystem ACLs on by default, just use setfacl to give 'ftpuser' the rights:

```
setfacl -R -m u:ftpuser:rwx /var/www/myWebApp
```

See the man page for setfacl/getfacl if you've never used them before.

Comment: in addition to this acl you can also set the SUID and GUID bits to make sure the files are owned by the same user and or group.

Answer (score 3):

You could put 'ftpuser' into the apache group, so group level permissions would apply instead of 'everyone'.

```
usermod -G ftpuser,apache ftpuser
```

This will change the users groups to both ftpuser and apache.

Answer (score 2):

Combine two user in one group, and adjust directory rights to this group. Or, simply run vsftpd under 'apache' user.